# Database agnostic schema access of data types?

Tags: .net, sql, database-schema

The general DbConnection.GetSchema methods [don't provide standardized schema collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254501%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) across databases, and [OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is database agnostic only up to the point where you need to access more detailed type information, like length of varchar and precision of numeric types.

Is there a way to obtain this schema information in a database-agnostic way? I understand that data type names will differ between databases, but all sql types fall into a few categories, ie. fixed length, variable length, etc., so this sort of information ought to be accessible in a database agnostic fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. A lot of the reason is that most database vendors don't strictly comply with the ANSI or ISO database standards.

A good discussion can be found [in this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784900/why-do-no-databases-fully-support-ansi-or-iso-sql-standards)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the different states of standards compliance between databases, but I was hoping at least that ADO.NET could standardize our data access method. Apparently that's asking too much as well.