# state of support of sql:X standards (ISO/IEC 9075:X)

Tags: sql, iso

is there any equivalent of [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) for the SQL ISO standard? is there any way to understand which ISO capability is implemented by which RDBMS, without digging into the docs of each and any version of each and any server?

thank you.

PS: related to, but not exactly the same of, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784900/why-does-no-database-fully-support-ansi-or-iso-sql-standards)

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words will give you some help.

Comment: unaware of this. seems really nice at first glance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems, however no ISO SQL related info.

Comment: The Postgres manual states for every command whether it's part of the standard or how their implementation deviates from the standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I know it is quite accurate, but I was asking for a solution to avoid "digging into the docs of each and any version of each and any server"